# App stops after adding id attribute to a TextView

Tags: android, netbeans

When I try to add an id attribute to the TextView element, my app stops when I run the project. The project runs fine until I do this.

Here is the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
```

==>     android:id="@+id/question_text_view">

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/true_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/false_button" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I remove the attribute, the project once again runs when I start it.

PS It stops before anything is displayed in the emulator

Comment: add end tag `android:id="@+id/question_text_view"/>`

Comment: If your code here is exactly the code in your app then you deleted the "/" right before the ">" of your TextView - that's all.

Comment: What does logcat say? What's the exception? In your example you're not closing the textview properly, but that's not a runtime problem.

Comment: The logcat seems to be balking at a ClassCastException, Somehow I'm trying to cast a TextView as a Button, although all I've added is the id attribute to the layout file

Answer (score 0):

Your text view should look like:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/question_text_view"/>
```

Comment: I've tried adding it in at different places in the definition to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to clean and build the project